# server.conf json entry for preload[ ]

Tags: apache, r, opencpu

I want to preload a few packages in opencpu. I tried a few variations in preload[ ] in file /etc/opencpu/server.conf but it doesn't work. wondering what is the correct syntax that goes into "preload[]" array field ? any example would help.

Comment: find.package() returns the package in "preload[]" array but not search()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be a vector of package names, e.g:

```
"preload": ["ggplot2", "MASS", "lme4"]
```

Note that packages that are preloaded are not attached. Hence, they show up in sessionInfo() but not in search(). This is to prevent side-effects or masking-conflicts.

Once a package has been preloaded, attaching it should be almost instant.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, I did add this to my /etc/opencpu/server.conf file.How do I verify that these packages indeed got loaded ? I run search() vial the /R/pub/base/identity/json API but it doesn't return "ggplot2" or "MASS" in the list.

Comment: It should. Did you do `sudo service opencpu-server restart` afterwards? And `sudo service opencpu-cache restart` if you are running the caching server?

Comment: I did restart the server. Interestingly the packages do show up when I run "sessionInfo()" but not in "search()". I am not running the cache server.

Comment: That is correct. The packages are preloaded, but not attached. This to prevent any unwanted side effects. But attaching the packages should be almost instant once it has been preloaded.

Comment: Is there a way to attach them as well. The reason I need it is that I have developed and installed a package mypkg which has a dataframe DF in data/directory and function myfunc() in R directory. Thus function internally accesses DF. Now unless I do library(mypkg), invoking myfunc1() returns error saying DF not exported. I thought preload would take care of it.

Comment: I am not quite sure why you would want to do that. If your function depends on `mypkg` you should load it somewhere in the code, or use `mypkg::DF` to access the data frame. I don't think it is a good idea to write your package in such a way that it requires modification of server settings to work. The `preload` option is there just to boost performance, it should not actually alter behavior of your function calls.

Comment: Because the function itself is part of the package "mypkg" along with DF. so accessing data that is part of the same package as the function itself via :: didn't look right to me.

Comment: for example: should I write the exported function myfunc() which is part of "mypkg" package as  myfunc() {  x<-mypkg::DF, print x } or myfunc() { x<- DF, print x} The latter seems natural as both data and function are part of same package.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OpenCPU. Test your package on your local R first. You probably need to do data(DF) somewhere, or disable lazy loading. Read the 'writing R exentions' manual and search for `LazyData`.